# How to handle authentication header using node.js?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, jwt

I was creating a token authentication server using jsonwebtoken.

my index_client.js code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/:id',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
    },
});
```

Get an access token from local storage and set the authentication header.

my mainRouter.js

```
router.get('/:id', checkToken, function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '/public/views/test.html'));
});
```

my checkToken.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
         console.log(req.headers.authorization);
         next();
    }
}
```

A problem occurred with the next() method.

When running the server and connecting with /:id url
The page is blank and the page loads indefinitely.

my console message

```
undefined
GET /123 304 10.042 ms - -
GET /index_client.js 304 2.249 ms - -
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Imp1bjA5MTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MzAyMTA0NTksImV4cCI6MTYzMDIxNDA1OSwiaXNzIjoiY290YWsifQ.nYnr862J2v8NjpIv287BUAXPdo-aYLSylmV4R0FQXDI
undefined
GET /favicon.ico 304 11.232 ms - -
```

Why am I getting the console message 3 times and the access token only once?

I searched for an answer to this, but couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are calling `next()` **only** when there is an authorization header. When there is no authorization header you are not doing anything. You need to call `next()` or send an error response using `res.end()`, `res.sendFile()` etc.

Comment: This answer was really helpful! Thanks to you, I was able to solve it! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every middleware must either call `next()` or respond with `res.end()` (or `res.sendFile()` or something similar). In the absence of an `Authorization` header, your `checkToken` middleware does neither, therefore the request runs indefinitely, as you observed.

Note that your route `/:id` contains a [route parameter](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) `:id`, therefore it matches all three requests and `checkToken` is invoked every time:

```
GET /123
GET /index_client.js
GET /favicon.ico
```

Comment: This answer was really helpful! Thanks to you, I was able to solve it! thank you!